# Function Variable - API Response preg_split result and pass created variable to new function

Tags: php, function, soap, global-variables, preg-split

Hoping you can help me here. I am at a bit of a loss :/

I have a function that passes data via API to a server. It sends a response. I need to split the string that comes in and take the final result and make that a variable that can be used by future functions.

This is the result from the server once I have successfully passed the data

> CLIENTID=101410;CLIENTREF=MZABOX2382;CONTACTID=22975

This is shown by

```
echo($add_client_response->AddClientKYCResult);
```

From this I need to get the numbers only of the CLIENTID and strip everything else out.

I have this snippet of code so far that isn't working

```
function AddClientKYCResult ( $data, $pilot ) {
$add_client_response = preg_split('/;/', $result['Result']);
$clientId = preg_split('/=/', $spl[0][0]);
$clientRef = preg_split('/=/', $spl[1][0]);
$contactId = preg_split('/=/', $spl[2][0]);
return $data;
echo($clientId);
}
```

Can someone help on this one?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To take in cognizance that CLIENTID can be anywhere in the string.

```
$apiResponse = $add_client_response->AddClientKYCResult;
//$apiResponse = "CLIENTID=101410;CLIENTREF=MZABOX2382;CONTACTID=22975";

$add_client_response = explode(";",$apiResponse);
$result = [];
foreach($add_client_response as $part) {
      $partArr = explode("=", $part);      
      $result[$partArr[0]] = $partArr[1];
}

$clientId = $result["CLIENTID"];
$clientRef = $result["CLIENTREF"];
$contactId = $result["CONTACTID"];
echo("clientId = $clientId<br/>");
echo("clientRef = $clientRef<br/>");
echo("contactId = $contactId");
```

Comment: ($add_client_response->AddClientKYCResult) - This is where the result comes from, how would I incorporate that into your code - this one looks the best. I have tested it and using this string it works super! But I'll need it for each result from the result

Comment: Made changes to the code to accommodate any use case.

Comment: Thanks Tope, the code is perfect, but I need to pull from the $add_client_response result that is passed back from the database. in your $result['Result'] = "CLIENTID=101410;CLIENTREF=MZABOX2382;CONTACTID=22975"; it uses the static result from one response. Is there a way to get it each time from this - ($add_client_response->AddClientKYCResult)... The fact that there is a $clientId is perfect

Comment: Adjusted to take result from the $add_client_response->AddClientKYCResult

Comment: Super, thanks.. but now I get Warning: Illegal string offset when I run it with the return from the database, but if I run your commented out line it works fine. Also needed to add in a ; for the first line

Comment: Please, var_dump($add_client_response->AddClientKYCResult), so I can see you full detail and process it correctly.

Comment: string(52) "CLIENTID=101428;CLIENTREF=MZABOX2400;CONTACTID=22993" this is what I am getting

Comment: Adjusted, I assumed that $add_client_response->AddClientKYCResult was an array, it is actually the string, we are processing.  This should work.

Comment: You sir are a scholar and a gentleman! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Manually, this can be done in a dirty way using [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), or a bit nicer with the common stack of [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), [`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) and [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

```
<?PHP
    $string = "CLIENTID=101410;CLIENTREF=MZABOX2382;CONTACTID=22975";

    // approach #1 use explode
    // dirty, since it needs clientID to be the first parameter
    $split = explode(";",$string);
    $finalResult = str_replace("CLIENTID=","",$split[0]);
    var_dump($finalResult);

    // approach #2 use strpos
    // better if you want to handle errors
    $beginClientID = strpos($string,"CLIENTID=");
    $endClientID = strpos($string,";",$beginClientID);
    $clientID = substr($string,$beginClientID+strlen("CLIENTID="),$endClientID-($beginClientID+strlen("CLIENTID=")));
    var_dump($clientID);



?>
```